# Splitting a character by "." in R

Tags: r, strsplit

The following character needs to be split by "."

```
value <- "abcdefg.csv"
strsplit(value,".")
```

The output that I get is:

```
[[1]]
[1] "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
```

However, what I want is:

```
[[1]]
[1] "abcdefg" "csv"
```

Comment: Use `fixed = TRUE`

Comment: Just escape it `strsplit(value,"\\.")`

Comment: Okay .. That helps!